# C - Job print status

Tags: c, cups

I am writing a program for printing images and I can't seem to find a way to check the print job status. I know about the `lpstat -W completed` and `lpstat -W not-completed` commands but they don't actually show if the job was successful or not, they show if the job is in queue. For example, if the job failed because there is no ink or papers, the job would be listed as completed. Is there anything i can do to check the status? My printer is Samsung SCX-4300

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consult the device manufacturer for the API!

Comment: Yeah i thought of that but I'm trying to find out if there is another way.